# Question about (what I think is called) reverse causality

Tags: r, regression

I was messing around with R when I came on a result I don't understand. I basically created an independent variable that was caused by the dependent variable instead of the other way around. What surprised me was that when I included it in my regression it affected all the other coefficients. Omitted variable or collider bias only affect the variables related to the bias. Here all the variables were affected. Is this correct? What is this sort of bias or problem called?

Here is the R code I used:

```
N <- 10000
x <- rnorm(N)
w <- rnorm(N)
k <- rnorm(N)
y <- .8 * x + .4 * w + .6 * k + rnorm(N)
z <- .8 * y + rnorm(N)
summary(lm(y ~ x + w + k))
summary(lm(y ~ z + x + w + k))
```

Comment: Daniel, the answer as been cleaned up and corrected, hope it is clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a modeling/econometric/statistical perspective: reverse causality is not a bias, it is rather a theoretical concept so the above phenomenon is not what econometricians would call reverse causality. The closest term to what you're looking for is endogeneity, namely, the right variables are not exogenous (ie independent). In this case, the error term is correlated with $z$; thus, the main issue with the above estimates would be their inconsistency (which is different from bias).

In regard to different coefficient estimates, note that originally (albeit simplified), you have $$ y = .8x +\varepsilon$$ so $\hat{\beta_x} = .8$ in your regression - as expected. *Note, the stuff below is just to give an intuitive picture, it is not a formal derivation*

Now, you are trying to estimate $y = \beta_z z+ \beta_x x$ where $z = .8y + \delta$. The true parameters are $\beta_z= 1.25$ and $\beta_x = .8$ so in essence you force the equation to be
$$y = 1.25z + .8 x + \varepsilon$$
and still expect $\hat{\beta_x}= .8$ which won't work. To know what to expect, note that $1.25z = 1.25(.8y+\delta) = .8x\approx y$ so what's actually happening is that you're estimating $\theta = (\theta_z, \theta_x)$

$$2y = \theta_z y_z + \theta_x y_x + u  = $$
$$y = .5y_z + .5y_x + u$$
where $u$ is some error term. As a result, in your regression you'll get that $\hat{\theta_z} \approx .5$ and $\hat{\theta_x} \approx .5$ but in you interpret the $\theta$s as $\beta_z$ and $\beta_x$ respectively; hence the dissonance.

**Caveat:** the above logic works if $x$ and $z$ have coefficients close to 1 and are similar. The further the coefficients go away from 1, the further away the estimates will be from .5. If the coefficients are uneven (note that $1.25*.8*.8 = .8 $) then the $\theta$ weights won't be equal.

For how these are handled in the modeling, check out [Woolridge](http://fmwww.bc.edu/ec-c/f2010/228/EC228.f2010.nn16.pdf) for simultaneous equation modeling. Instrumental variables you'll find all over the net.

As an illustration:

```
> N <- 10000
> x <- rnorm(N)
> w <- rnorm(N)
> k <- rnorm(N)
> y <- .8 * x +   + rnorm(N)
> z <- .8 * y + rnorm(N)
> summary(lm(y ~ x ))

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.9247 -0.6855  0.0071  0.6718  3.6579 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 0.0001747  0.0099707   0.018    0.986    
x           0.8078591  0.0100123  80.687   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.9969 on 9998 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.3944,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.3943 
F-statistic:  6510 on 1 and 9998 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

> summary(lm(y ~ z + x ))

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ z + x)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.96427 -0.52940 -0.00263  0.53562  2.75652 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 0.001066   0.007847   0.136    0.892    
z           0.482697   0.006157  78.393   <2e-16 ***
x           0.498449   0.008813  56.559   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.7846 on 9997 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6249,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6249 
F-statistic:  8328 on 2 and 9997 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful. I suppose my larger question is does this mean in any regression if the DV is a cause of one of the IV's then all the coefficients are going to be way off. For example, if I was examining a regression that said Growth = Unemployment + Spending + Trade + Weather. But if Growth actually caused Spending, rather than the other way around, would it bias all the other coefficient estimates?

Comment: You raise a valid concern. It would likely bias estimates but your bigger fear is that the estimates will be inconsistent. In such cases, you would either estimate the two equations simultaneously or find an instrumental variable that is exogenous. Check out Woolridge as they provide a good intro to this type of modeling in econometrics.